# How to change the color of a /dojox/mobile/ToolBarButton

Tags: javascript, button, colors, dojo

I guess it's a simple task, but I'm not able to change the color of a `dojox/mobile/ToolBarButton`:

```
h1(data-dojo-type="dojox/mobile/Heading") My Heading
        span#myButton(data-dojo-type="dojox/mobile/ToolBarButton" dojo-type="dojox/mobile/ToolBarButton" data-dojo-props="arrow:'right', label:'My Button'" style="float:right;")
```

Inside a javascript function I want to change the color of the button, like I can do during startup using:

```
defaultColor:'mblRedButton'
```

or

```
defaultColor:'mblBlueButton'
```

Of course adding that class to the DOM node it's not enough. But I don't understand how should I do it.

### UPDATE

Still unsolved but I add that I tried to add the class `mblBlueButton` to the dom node of the button without success. Inspecting the classes at run-time I see the button is actually composed of several items. Each one has the original class. I wonder how to change them all.

Comment: Have you tried `myButton.set("defaultColor", "mblRedButton")` ?

Comment: Yes, but it will be new the color only after any event. i.e. I need to click the button to reload the `defaultColor`, because AFAIK this property is read only when the widget is loaded.